# Multiple &nbsp; being added automatically in Visual Studio html editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I feel very bad with a visual studio behavior of adding lots of nbsp to the html editor automatically. Thats make lots of alignment issues for the design. Requesting any kind of solution for this.
Some one in stackoverflow said its because editor opening while running the application. That may be reason but closing the editor when ever running the application is not a solution..

expecting a real solution for that MS bug
[image]

Comment: Did you have that file open in "design" view or "code" view? Could you have pressed the spacebar while in design view?

Comment: Mine is in code view (Markup view)